# Javascript: How to get a unique list of values assigned to the same property from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique, javascript-objects

*I'm trying to make a unique list of all the values assigned to the city property, which is buried in an object within an object, and I have an array of such objects*

`buildings = [
    {
        name: 'Victoria Bell Tower',
        filterOptions: {
            city: 'Ottowa',
            state: 'Canada',
            buildingType: 'Parliament Building',
        },
    },
    {
        name: 'Cathedral',
        filterOptions: {
            city: 'Washington D.C.',
            state: '',
            buildingType: 'Cathedral',
        },
    },
    {
        name: 'Post Office',
        filterOptions: {
            city: 'Washington D.C.',
            state: '',
            buildingType: 'Post Office',
        },
    }]`

*What's a practical way to get a unique array of the cities properties:*

`cities = ['Ottowa', 'Washington D.C.']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try my simple code:

```
let arr = buildings.map(b => {
  return b.filterOptions.city
})
console.log([...new Set(arr)]);
```

Comment: This doesn't remove dups, though right? I need uniqe values for a dropdown

Comment: Do you try? This is a demo: https://codepen.io/phuongnm153/pen/oNgreZy

Comment: @Mugunga It would because of the use of `Set` which filters out duplicates

Comment: Ah, yes that works, thank you. Why does it need the [... ] around the new set instead of just: log(new Set(arr));